# Weird angular behaviour in (click) - need to add 'true;' to update UI if setting a false value

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

Was stuck for ages on a radio button in angular yesterday, and not the usual 'can't get checked to work' stuff either

Basically if I set a variable to false in a (click) function, the UI won't update but the variable will (the example angular html code is below with a link - try clicking the first group to yup then nope...)

In the second group I have to add a 'true;' to the (click) statement to get the UI to update i.e. show the correct radio button selection

The third group uses vanilla type/javascript onclick functions. The variable doesn't update (I don't expect it to), but the UI does with the same 'variable = false' statement as the original group.

Is this some sort of angular wrinkle I should know about or a bug?

```
<p>Group 1, value = {{isYes}}</p>
<label>Nope<input type="radio" name="group1" id="nope" (click)="isYes = false;" checked></label>
<label>Yup<input type="radio" name="group1" id="yup" (click)="isYes = true;"></label>

<p>Group 2, value = {{isYes2}}</p>
<label>Nope<input type="radio" name="group2" id="nope2" (click)="isYes2 = false; true;" checked></label>
<label>Yup<input type="radio" name="group2" id="yup2" (click)="isYes2 = true;"></label>

<p>Group 3, value = {{isYes3}}</p>
<label>Nope<input type="radio" name="group3" id="nope3" onclick="this.isYes3 = false;" checked></label>
<label>Yup<input type="radio" name="group3" id="yup3" onclick="this.isYes3 = true;"></label>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lrte3r?file=src/app/app.component.html

Windows 10 Pro, Chrome 91 (but does the same in Firefox)

---

Edit:
This still updates the UI correctly, even though it returns false for nope

```
<p>Group 3, value = {{isYes3}}</p>
<label>Nope<input type="radio" name="group3" id="nope3" onclick="return false;" checked></label>
<label>Yup<input type="radio" name="group3" id="yup3" onclick="return true;"></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Angular wrinkle. In group 1, the event bubbles up stopping it from being changed again. In group 2, the `true` stop it. Ideally you would use JS [`Event#stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

```html
<p>Group 1, value = {{isYes}}</p>
<label>Nope<input type="radio" name="group1" id="nope" (click)="isYes = false; $event.stopPropagation();" checked></label>
<label>Yup<input type="radio" name="group1" id="yup"  (click)="isYes = true;"></label>
```

Group 3 with vanialla JS `onclick` <s>is not recognized</s> cannot access controller variables (like `isYes3 = true`) when used in Angular and hence they would have no effect.

I've modified the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-endtpz?file=src/app/app.component.html).

---

That said, there are more elegant and advanced ways in Angular for form control where you don't have to assign the variable manually. Look into [Angular forms overview](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview).

Comment: so why doesn't it happen in group 3?

Comment: @mgraham: I was just updating the answer.

Comment: Group 3 does work though, if you add alerts into the onclick's they trigger

Comment: @mgraham: Perhaps _"not recognized"_ is misleading. The final DOM generated by the compiler would be plain JS and so `onclick` would be recognized by the browser. But `onclick` cannot support native Angular features like accessing/adjusting member variables (eg. `isYes3 = true`).

Comment: yeh, I didn't expect the variable to change as what I'm reffing in the onclicks aren't the same scope even if it's the same name. What I don't get is why the UI doesn't update on clicking 'nope' in group 1, but does in 'yup'.  Even in group3 if I return false or true rather than do anything with a variable the UI updates, but in group 1 it doesn't. It seems angular must do something? Anyways, stopPropagation() looks better than true; :-)